# How to stop listening on a stream in python gRPC client

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I am listening in a python thread on a gRPC stream that never ends:

```
responses = some_grpc_stub.FunctionThatReturnsStream()
for response in responses:
  on_event(response)
```

I want to do this for a while, and then *stop* listening, so that `on_event` isn't called again, possibly before the stream is done.

How do I do that? Is there a correct way to just kill the thread in which this loop is running? Or is there some way to have `responses` end prematurely so iteration ends and the thread can run to completion?

Comment: Which gRPC Python API are you using? Future or AsyncIO?

Comment: I had been using asyncio but I'm willing to use whatever accomplishes this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can consider using `cancel()`[1]? The streaming call returns an object that is both a Future and an iterator, you can invoke `responses.cancel()` to cancel it. In practice, this needs to happen in another thread, because the consumption of the iterator blocks.

If you are using AsyncIO API, the invoking a streaming call returns an object that implemented `asyncio.Task`, and supports `cancel` [2]. You can still use `responses.cancel()` to stop a stream.

[1] https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.RpcContext.cancel

[2] https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel

Comment: Yep, works! It might be nice to make that a bit clearer in the examples that involve iterating over a stream. If you don't object, lmk, and I might make a PR adding it.

Comment: Improvements are always welcomed! Feel free to @ me in the PR.